# file within directory contains entire directory's current sha-256

Tags: git, githooks, sha256

I want to create a file in my directory, where the file contains the sha256 sum of that directory, including that file, and AFTER the file is created. The difficulty here being that the sha256 of the directory will be affected by updating the file with said sha256. Is this possible?

I can see how this is almost asking the computer to predict the future, but I wonder if there is some recursive algorithm to do this. For example if there is some consistent relation between the checksum of and object, and the checksum of that object with one byte changed.

This is a question of curiosity that came out of this problem: I'm trying to recreate the output of `git describe --tags` for a repository missing the .git directory (presumably saving this data in the repository).

Comment: What's the usefulness of this? As long as the file is in the repo, the commit ID can be easily retrieved using Git. When the repo is gone (when the files are exported, f.e.) the commit ID is useless. Even more, Git commit IDs change when the commits are rebased.

Comment: I want to use the commit ID (more specifically the output of `git describe --tags`) to tag the build artifact, where the build process (here in AWS codepipeline) uses the exported files rather than the entire repository.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. There might not even be a solution. To take a simple example: imagine that the value of a SHA256 hash was only 1 bit, instead of 256 bits. Suppose that, if we put the hash `0` into the file, the entire directory hashes to a value of `1`; and if we put `1` into the file, the entire directory hashes to a value of `0`. Then there is no solution. The same thing can happen with the full 256-bits hash. I'm not sure of the likelyhood though.

If there is a solution, you can eventually find it with an exhaustive search of all possible checksums. By the very nature of secure hashes, it won't get significantly faster than that. But this will probably run until the Sun becomes a red giant and swallows the Earth.

To improve your actual situation (beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), you can try instructing your build system to stick the result of `git rev-parse HEAD` somewhere in a source file before building, or have your program execute this at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. Though I don't understand your first paragraph. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm just saying that there is no guarantee that the checksum you are looking for even exists. I've clarified by giving an example.